# Fundamental reasons for not allowing multi-arguments operator[] in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, multidimensional-array, standards, subscript

Currently, we can only overload `operator[]` with exactly one argument.

I would like to know if there is a fundamental reason why the standard does not allow to overload `operator[]` for several arguments ?

Are there propoposals in this way for C++17 ?

Comment: counterquestion: is there any fundamental reason why you can't use the `operator()`?

Comment: @PeterT: I was looking to multi-array discussions for future proposals in which workarounds of this limitation are discussed. So I wonder if there was a fundamental reason why multi-arguments operator[] cannot be considered for a core modification of C++...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This probably *could* be added, but *shouldn't*, because it **breaks existing code**.

Basically, what multiple arguments to `operator[]` would mean is that the following would compile:

```
struct Foo
{
    int operator[](int a, int b, int c)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    auto n = foo[1, 2, 3]; // list of parameters
}
```

However consider this:

```
int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    std::vector<int> bar(4, 0);
    auto n = foo[1, 2, 3]; // list of parameters
    auto x = bar[1, 2, 3]; // comma operator! returning the 3rd element of bar. valid syntax
}
```

This would mean, that in an expression using comma inside of square brackets can either be a list of parameters or the use of the comma operator.
Therefore, there could only ever be exactly one valid number for the arguments of operator[], meaning this couldn't be resolved:

```
struct Foo
{
    int operator[](int a, int b, int c)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int operator[](int a)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

There is no way to dissolve the ambiguity of `1, 2, 3` here. This means: if the standard would change to allow this, any code using the comma operator in calls to `operator[]` would become a compile error. The standard commitee tries hard to not break existing code (which is a good thing!) with the introduction of new features. In my opinion, this would be quite a radical change and is therefore unlikely to be done.

If you want multiple arguments, either use a different operator (as Mike suggested, `operator()` would work) or pass a `std::tuple` or equivalent.

Comment: "Never break existing code" is a bit too strong.  "Only break existing code if there is a strong reason to".  There are myriad breaking changes in every revision: and in the future, nearly every modification to an interface will be theoretically breaking, as we can have code that behaves conditionally on if certain expressions *do not* compile.

Comment: @Yakk Afaik they try as hard as they can to avoid breaking things. Sure, if e.g. new keywords are added, this can break things, but they surely wouldn't do such a radical change in terms of the comma operator. I altered my formulation slightly.

Answer (score 5):

> I would like to know if there is a fundamental reason why the standard does not allow to overload `operator[]` for several arguments ?

No fundamental reason; just the general principle that overloaded operators have the same syntax as the built-in operator they overload.

> Are there propoposals in this way for C++17 ?

No. A common alternative is to overload `operator()`; that can take as many arguments as you like.